# Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

I was recently searching for a question that I found an answer to on a Google groups site.  If I had not found the answer on that site, I probably would have asked the question on SO.  Which has got me thinking.

My questions can be broken into two.

1. Should I consider questions already answered on non-SE sites but within the domain of SO to be good questions to ask on SE?  The reason would be that many users (such as me) prefer the format of SE to that of other sites?
2. If I were to duplicate a question from another site, what degree of modification of the question would be necessary so that it does not risk copyright infringement?

Comment: Are questions really copyrightable? Not sure about that.

Comment: for your first point, I guess, that one can ask dup-non-SE questions, because, purpose of SE is to gather the knowledge and there is also a chance that you can get a better answer here. But, this is just my point-of-view and/or opinion. I am not an expert in these matters.

Comment: you can see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/451859) answer, which is somewhat supports my previous point, because it has upvotes. The solution is copied from another forum in this case.

Comment: If they have already been answered, why would you ask them?

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like the way how this is addressed at Java Ranch:

### [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/BeForthrightWhenCrossPostingToOtherSites)

> ...keep in mind that this is not generally in the interests of the posters who might be responding to your posts - those folks may find they've wasted their time. You certainly don't want to annoy those you want to help you, so you might want to make the experience as painless as possible.
>
> The best way to do something like this (without ticking people off) would be to let people know upfront that the crossposting is occurring. This makes the most sense if there's a respectable delay between posting in one forum and another, e.g:
>
> "I posted this question the other day in SomeOtherForum.com [link], but wasn't able to get a good answer, so now I'm asking here..."
>
> A responsible netizen might also post a followup in SomeOtherForum.com letting people there know if a better answer is found.

<sub>copied from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/165773</sub>

Comment: duplicate!!! oh wait, it is cross-site. :P :D

Comment: Cross posting a answer that says that you should tell if your cross posting. I see what you did. :)