# Is content reposted from another site acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was looking at this post today:
[TFS NuGet tricks that I don't already know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855672/tfs-nuget-tricks-that-i-dont-already-know-about)

It looks fine enough, but then I saw [this identical](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/390639) post on a different web site, which is dated a couple of days before.

Even the edits match exactly (an edit to the SO post appears verbatim as a follow-up comment on the other site).

The posters of each post might very well be the same person (look at the poster's names), but there is no guarantee, of course. there is no indication on the SO post indicating that the question is being re-asked from another location, which makes me uncomfortable about its legitimacy.

My questions are:

> 1. Assuming this is the same person honestly looking for answer in two places: Is it acceptable for the same person to post questions on one site and then repost the same verbatim question in SO, without mention of the original post location? Or should the poster mention the other place where the content has been posted?

I think that there is an interesting issue of potential copyright conflict, because if you post content on site A and then on SO, the content might be affected by a contractual obligation attached to the site A (for example, site A might require you to relinquish copyrights on the content, in which case reposting to SO might be a copyright violation on the part of the original poster, even if they created the content originally).

And:

> 2. Should I notice something like this in the future, is the appropriate action to flag for moderator review? Or add a comment on the post alerting of the possible plagiarism? Ignore it?

Thanks!

Comment: farina looks awfully much like a reversed aniraf..

Comment: The author of a post retains the right to their own works, it is perfectly fine for them to re-post it somewhere else. Stack Overflow does **not** ask you to relinquish your copyright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites)

Comment: @Konqui please stop bumping old post making stupid edits.  Yes, the link formatting you are doing might be better but bumping dozens of old posts just to make this one edit is the almost worthless

Comment: I don't see any problem. The site is not even a member of stackexchange family.

Answer (score 5):

> Assuming this is the same person honestly looking for answer in two places: Is it acceptable for the same person to post questions on one site and then repost the same verbatim question in SO, without mention of the original post location? Or should the poster mention the other place where the content has been posted?

Give the names of the posters are the same except one is backwards (farina => aniraf), I'd venture a guess that it is one and the same.  He/She had a problem, posted it on codeplex and Stack Overflow, found the answer after some troubleshooting & dialogue on CodePlex, so decided to spread the knowledge by posting the solution as an answer on SO.  Seems pretty innocent to me.

> Should I notice something like this in the future, is the appropriate action to flag for moderator review? Or add a comment on the post alerting of the possible plagiarism? Ignore it?

Depends on the nature of the infraction.  Copying a question word-for-word is probably ok in most cases.  It is probably just someone looking for help in multiple places, so cross posting on multiple sites doesn't seem to be a problem, especially if the time stamps are similar and it appears that it is the same user.  Generally speaking, questions do not seem to have the same level of scrutiny in terms of proper citation, as they are usually someone asking for help and not sources of original work.

On the other hand, copying answers found on other sites though is most of a problem since you are "stealing" someone else's work.  You should encourage someone to cite references in their answers so they can give proper credit to the original author.

I'd avoid flagging for a single infraction though.  Not much a mod can do that a regular user can't do.  However, if the user seems to have a history of doing it, then it is time to involve a moderator, by flagging the post, selecting "Other", and explaining the full story including links.