# How do I handle duplicates when they are asked on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

I recently saw the same question asked in two SE sites and I got curious.

What should I do if I am answering a question and there is an answer on another SE site. Should I flag the question as a duplicate and link the question on the other site or should I simply link the question on the other SE site?

edit:
I did read this: [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites?rq=1) but it seems to imply that the question was not yet answered. I'm referring to cases in which the question is already answered.

Comment: According to [Tim's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251428/464709) to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251375/464709), the content should be duplicated and we should not worry about it. *(Disclaimer: I personally disagree with that assertion.)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Cross site duplicates between child metas and meta.SE are a bit of a special case, when compared to just duplicates between two regular SE sites...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the general case: post a comment saying that it's already been answered elsewhere and link to it if you want, do nothing at all because it's not a problem, or use the other question as a resource when posting your own answer. The system doesn't recognise the concept of cross site duplicates; if you're voting to close as a duplicate, the question you're saying already has the answer has to be on the same site.

However, in the case that it's the exact same question, asked by the same user, on more than one Stack Exchange site, I'd either flag for moderator attention or use a custom close reason to make it clear that it's been cross posted to multiple sites, which [isn't allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069).

Comment: Do you know where the cross-posting to multiple SE sites ban is documented?

Comment: Found it, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/178985)