# Cross-posting between localized Stack Overflow versions

Tags: discussion, languages, cross-posting, portuguese-stack-overflow, international-sites

Cross-posting between Stack Exchange sites is disapproved as we can see in [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667)

But with the arrival of localized Stack Overflow sites ([Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) is online and there are [much more to come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hyvm.png)), how should we deal with this here at the Big SO Brother?

At SOPT, it's being encouraged: ["Q: Where do I ask? A: Ask in both!](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.pt.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F735%2Fonde-fa%C3%A7o-pergunta-so-em-portugu%C3%AAs-ou-em-ingl%C3%AAs). Personally, I agree, as it'll be much harder for someone to speak Portuguese here than English there.

I'm advocating (through comments, no Meta yet) that people disclose that they are cross-posting here when they duplicate the question there. And I'd like feedback about: should it be disclosed here that there's a duplicate question over there?

Comment: Pardon what might seem like cultural insensitivity, but if you can post (and understand the answers) in English on the English Stack Overflow site, why post it in Portuguese at all? Is there really a need to cross-post then?

Comment: It's not me. I think SOpt is thriving and there's lots of excellent coders over there, just like SOen. It's a situation I've been observing and the "no cross-posting" policy is being overruled there. What to do here?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you-you, I mean everyone-you, generalising. =)

Comment: I'd assume it's because someone disagrees and doesn't have a more eloquent point than that. I'm interesting in hearing the discussion so I'm not disagreeing yet. =)

Comment: If cross-posting is frowned upon everywhere else, then it would be inconsistent for SOpt to be any different. If people can ask it clearly in English, then they should **either** post it on SOen *or* SOpt, but not both. If they can't ask it clearly in English, then they should just post it on SOpt. Permitted cross posting would be a hard sell to the majority of SOen I suspect, and if people disclose that it's a cross post, expect it to be downvoted to oblivion and closed.

Comment: By virtue of non-comprehension I ignore everything at SOpt, and if I can't understand the twin I'm not going to be offended that it's a duplicate. Is there an issue arising from having the question in both places?

Comment: @J.Steen Just from memory I can refer you to one question that I did cross-post and was ignored here, but actually elicited a useful reply on the Portuguese sister site; by probing both in parallel I managed to get some work done. I'd say that's a compelling argument towards a positive view of cross-posting.

Comment: @OnoSendai, hope you brought the solution to SOen to make a win-win :)

Comment: @brasofilo We want a better SO experience for all. Of course it's a win-win. ;)

Comment: _should it be disclosed_ -- most definitely yes. **["Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251475/839601)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cross-post is discouraged among SE sites because you're basically talking to the same demographic, only possibly misplacing your questions (regarding scope, that is.)

Cross-posts between localized versions aim to reach different demographics in parallel, effectively evading the main concern: content replication by overlapping.

That said, the fact that the question is being asked in two (or possibly more) localized versions is irrelevant to those who only attend one of them.

IMHO the disclosure is *well-intended*, but *not necessary*.

Answer (score 8):

To quote myself in my answer to [Is it OK to crosspost Stack Overflow questions, now that the Portuguese SO is open?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218055/is-it-ok-to-crosspost-stack-overflow-questions-now-that-the-portuguese-so-is-op/218056#218056) from MSE

> The whole reason cross posting is discouraged is it splits answers and comments between communities, however, the guideline was established when you had 2 sites with different but overlapping scopes, not 2 sites with identical scopes merely differing in the accepted language of the site.
>
> Personally, I still don't think cross posting is the best option. Assuming you speak both languages well enough to translate, I think you should pick the site that think would give you the best answer, and ask it there.
>
> If the question is really a good question and gets several good answers, then repost it in the other site. You can self answer with 1 or more of the good answers you already got, translated into the other language (preferably as CW and attributed to the original poster). Then if either question gets additional good answers, you can add them in the future in the same manner. I think it will require some maintenance on your part, but I think it would be helpful to avoid problems of good questions being unavailable to users who don't speak the appropriate language.

But to add something else that I posted as a comment to the original answer

> I don't want to endorse cross posting until the asker is sure the question is valuable. If someone cross posts a bad question on both sites, then you are forcing 2 different communities to clean up the same question. At least by testing it on 1 site, you give the community a chance to accept it, clean it up, and upvote it.

So don't cross post for the sake of cross posting.  If you think the question (and answers) are valuable to the general community, then it is ok to cross post it, but don't make 2 different communities clean up a crap post.

Comment: +1 - specially for the part about the extra effort to replicate content between languages, and the benefits of it.

Answer (score 5):

Considering that any time you have a legitimate reason for reasking an existing question, you should link to whatever prior information you know about, it seems a no-brainer that cross-language duplicates posted by the same author should link to each other.  It's of direct benefit to all people who can read both languages, and eventually to everyone visiting either question, as the bilingual users carry knowledge across.

Knowing that there's a related discussion going on and hiding it from the people you hope will answer your question may not be an outright deletion offense, but it definitely goes against netiquette.