# Translating questions and answers between localized SO sites

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, portuguese-stack-overflow

I had a look at [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) and noticed that many high reputation users had amassed a massive amount of reputation points partly through translating answers to questions from the original SO site. And sometimes even asking and answering the questions themselves, with both question AND answer taken from original SO.

I'm wondering what's the official stance on this. Is this behaviour acceptable? Is it perhaps even encouraged?

My initial reaction is that if your entire content is just a translation, it should be labeled community wiki. Even though it's a translation, I just fail to see how this isn't plagiarization if you post it under your own name. Especially if both question and answer are copied/translated.

EDIT:
I disagree that this is a dupe of [Same question posted and answered on different Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317106/same-question-posted-and-answered-on-different-stack-overflow-sites) That question is about people cross-posting their own questions, my question is about users copying and translating OTHER users' questions and answers. So more about plagarization other people's contents than about the effect of cross-posting your own question.

Comment: I can see why it might be useful to go ahead and add the commonly asked/canonical Q&As but if they aren't even citing where the original content comes from, I agree that's a problem.

Comment: No, it seems answers are being cited (at least sometimes, I can't account for all answers) but from what I can see questions are not. And this seems to be habitual behavior for some users. I'm just wondering what the official stance on this is. For all I know this is an encouraged behaviour.

Comment: Maybe rather than having localized Q&A data/userbases we could have a "Translate this question/answer" feature on the global site. But that would scale very poorly taking into account all the crap we get.

Comment: @BoltClock The SO team has been pretty clear about how they want to (try to) handle languages. There's already [plenty](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/) of [discussion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) about that. I'd say what we need now is an official stance on how to handle these kinds of situations.

Comment: Are the rules different about attribution when it is within the network?

Comment: I don't think so. If someone were to create an answer using some content from an existing SO post, they'd be expected to provide attribution (in the case where the question they're answering isn't a dupe).

Comment: @BSMP This is more specifically about dupes across networks (cross-posting, if you will), and of creating said cross-network dupes with the aim of answering it yourself. It's a bit special, because if it happened on normal SO you'd mark the question a dupe, but if you copy the question to another network it becomes the canonical QA on there. On normal SO, people'd visit the original and upvote it. Here, your localized dupe becomes the de facto answer (with maybe just a link somewhere in the answer that you didn't write it yourself).

Comment: Maybe some method to mark a question as a "dupe" (having been asked and answered) across networks should be applicable? Then the people who has a moderate understanding of the other language could clearly see that more answers exist and could also benefit from the other answers to said question? I dunno, the whole deal just smells kinda shady for me as it's currently being used.

Comment: Sorry, my "I don't think so" comment was in response to @Tim's question about attribution rules.

Comment: *"massive amount of points partly through translating answers to questions from the original SO site"* - Can you please take more serious steps, like flagging, opening a meta question over there, writing to SE team?.... Because what you're saying is that there are users engaging in something akin to professional plagiarism in SOpt. And to say that you must have collected a minimum of solid evidence. I don't think "not attributing your sources" is an encouraged behavior by any metric.

Comment: I haven't said people aren't attributing sources. And I don't know enough portuguese to ask on portuguese Meta, that's why I'm asking here. I don't want to single anyone out, I'm asking what the official stance on this is. Is this allowed? And is it even encouraged? Should users gain massive rep by simply translating popular questions and answers? Is that the main idea of how the sites are supposed to work? Or shouldn't the questions and answers rather be Community Wiki, if the answer (and sometimes question) came from the community and not you?

Comment: Like I said I don't want to single anyone out in case this is viewed as totally acceptable and encouraged behaviour. But let's take as some examples http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402 <- almost the same question and looks like word-for-word answer translation and http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477 <- this question is translated and self answered based on the answer from the original question. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797 <- And another. Many of these questions have even been awarded bounties.

Comment: To cite or not to cite **is** to attribute or not. If you don't speak the language, how can you tell it's a translation "word by word"? Two of the examples you provide are citing the originals. I fail to see what's your exact problem. FWIW, people took a huge job of writing walls of texts on what seem very useful questions, the least they deserve is exactly that: reputation.

Comment: I said I don't speak it *well enough* to post in it myself, not that I don't understand it at all. Interesting that instead of denying that it's a straight up translation, you try to throw doubt at my language abilities... People took a huge job of *translating* walls of text, not writing them, and that's the entire crux of my question. I know already that reputation is more of a measurement of involvement than actual knowledge, but with the massive points for "just" translating, it becomes a rep-for-translating service. Again, that might be totally intended, *hence my questions*.

Comment: And according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing you should "quote only the relevant portions". If your whole post is a translation, then your whole post is a quote, and should be within quotes, right? Or are the rules somehow different between languages? And what are those rules? If rules for this don't exist, *they should*, even if said rules say "this is totally ok and we want our users to do this". And again, from the linked questions, the answers are sometimes cited but the (self-answered, translated, bounty-awarded) questions are not.

Comment: Using the term 'just' for translation is a bit off; translation (especially good translation in a niche area) is *hard*.

Comment: @Yakk that's why "just" is within quotes. I'd say there's definitely a difference between "just" translating (or quoting if you will) and adding some of your own knowledge to a post though, and the "just" is about highlighting that difference. Maybe "just" translating is partly what http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ is supposed to be about though and what users are supposed to get rep for. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I think you need to incorporate your thoughts about "rep-for-translation service" into this question. We all know it's one thing to take content from another answer and cite it; the question you're raising is really more, "What's SO's stance on users getting huge reputation gains for translating someone else's work, without having done the hard work to put together to content in the first place?"

Comment: @jpmc26 I thought that was exactly what I was saying in my question though

Comment: Some of the comments suggest you've been misunderstood, so some clarification is in order. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, it appears that the users of pt.stackoverflow.com seem to really appreciate good stackoverflow.com posts being well translated.

Comment: The parent dupe would be http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270047/1079354, which *does* seem to echo your concerns...

Comment: @Makoto no I'd say that's as dissimilar as the original suggested dupe and for the same reasons. The new dupe http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311528/points-awarded-to-original-answers-in-translated-sites seems to touch close enough on the same subject, though I disagree that it "has been answered". None of the answers have been accepted and with good reason I'd say, none of them actually address the issue, they just all confirm that they don't know how to handle it.