# Same question posted and answered on different Stack Overflow sites

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462969/how-to-erase-a-macro-using-another-one) today, which the OP has posted [a low quality/link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464889/4240221) to.

The link that was posted as an answer leads to an answer on the portuguese SO site, to [the exact same question, by the same OP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113759/excluir-uma-macro-usando-outra).

I accidentally retracted my initial close vote of "unclear" so I'm unable to currently check - but I have 2 questions:

1. Is it okay for someone to post the same question on different SO sites in another language?
2. Will the "already has an answer" option accept a link to another SO language site?

I've flagged it for mod attention, but haven't seen this before so though I'd throw it on meta.

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305696/translating-questions-and-answers-between-localized-so-sites

Comment: Beat me to it by 13 seconds @rene. I'd argue one of them qualifies as a dupe

Comment: sorry, but that one didn't have an answer and here Servy wrote something that makes sense @CubeJockey Maybe dupe vote the other way around?

Comment: @rene Yeah, probably better in that orientation, with an answer being here.

Comment: I've a dupe hammer and I'm not 100% sure so I leave it to others to decide...

Comment: I disagree that they are dupes. This question is about people cross-posting their own questions, my question was about users copying and translating OTHER users' questions and answers. So more about plagarization other people's contents than about the effect of cross-posting your own question. I'd say it's quite clearly a different question, and one that remains to be answered (no one has even attempted to answer it).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is it okay for someone to post the same question on different SO sites in another language?

It's perfectly fine for the same question to be posted to multiple SO sites for different languages.  Of course, the question would need to be in the language of each site, and follow all of the rules of the site that it's on.

Someone taking a quality question and translating it (well, ideally) to another language is *adding value*.  If you feel that the question merits closure *irrespective of the fact that it's posted on multiple sites*, then feel free to close it; if you don't feel that the question (or answer) is useful, feel free to vote accordingly.

> Will the "already has an answer" option accept a link to another SO language site?

No, nor should it.  People going to an English site aren't expected to speak Portuguese, or vice versa.

Comment: So - _(just so it's straight in my head)_ if the same question was asked again on the same SO site that would obviously be a duplicate, but we're saying that because the question _(presumably)_ doesn't yet appear on this particualr site it's adding value? (just to clarify, I'm not disputing or being sarcastic - just making sure I understand the answer properly for future reference)

Comment: @MacroMan The same conceptual question *asked in a different language* is a very different question.  Likewise, an answer provided *in a different language* is a very different answer.  It's not like it's just copy-pasting content from one site to another.  Do you honestly think that just because someone asked a question in Portuguese nobody would ever want to see it in English (or vice versa)?  Do you  just assume everyone in the world speaks every single language?

Answer (score -4):

Not only is it okay, it is a wonderful way to get some cross pollination going on.  This individual's English is better than my Portuguese, but I was able to edit his post to get his intent across.

As it turns out, the purpose of his question was to find out if there was a possible security exploit he should be aware of and was trying to devise a defense.

Prior to his asking the question, I was unaware that you actually could do what he said.  So, there is at least ONE user who learned quite a bit from that post.

He also posted the solution to his own question once he figured it out.

For his efforts, he lost 14 points to his rep.

I bookmarked the chip pearson link on that question, as I found it fascinating.

So, my question is, other than the poor English, which was edited, what made that a bad question?

Comment: `So, my question is, other than the poor English, which was edited, what made that a bad question?` But that's not what this meta question is all about.  If you want to ask that as your own meat question, that's fine.

Comment: Ah fer cryin out loud!  do you only read the last line of posts?

Comment: It looks like your entire answer is addressing the quality of the question, not whether or not it's inherently okay to cross post on different language sites.

Comment: No, I led with the point that it's a wonderful way to get some cross-pollination going on.  The rest was an explanation of why.  Unless SO is loaded with multilingual individuals, it's not duplication.