# Posting a question that is coming from another domain-specific forum

Tags: discussion, questions, cross-posting, forums

Sometimes I have questions that should also be asked on the specific library/framework official forum, but I'd also like to have it here to gain more possible answers/solutions.

Is this generally accepted? you see it as a bad, good practice or simply irrelevant?

Comment: related: [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251469/839601)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is question on-topic for SO? - if yes than go ahead and ask it.

Considerations before asking:

- If it is already answered elsewhere and answer is easy to find post should be downvoted into oblivion first. It may recover in over years if for some reason it is very popular question for that library so.
- If there are similar posts on SO it may be closed as duplicate (and downvoted too if easy to find duplicates)
- *Demonstrating* your research and clearly specifying what particular improvement over existing answers you are looking for is expected
- Transitional issues ("why site X is down today"/"why code from nightly build of library Y fails when...") are generally not suitable for SO. Make sure question is reasonable if found by someone year later.

Note that "the official forum" may have they own policy on cross-posting. Make sure to understand license that forum use for posts and whether/how cross-posts should be done.

Answer (score 2):

If it’s on topic, it’s on topic: being on topic elsewhere doesn’t make it off topic here. So yes, with caveats.

1. If you’re asking in two places, it’s probably polite to save duplication of effort on the part of answerers. If you get an answer in one place, then use that to provide a self-answer in the other. (This may mean simply copying the answer you get in one place to the other, depending on whether the relevant licenses of both sites allow that. Stack Overflow, for example, is CC BY-SA with attribution required. Or use the answer you get in one place to write your own answer in the other place, supplying appropriate attribution.)

   - In fact, even *before* you get an answer, it may be a good idea to link to the other question.
2. Cross-posting *may* be disallowed by the other forum. Check first.
3. [Cross-posting on multiple Stack Exchange sites is explicitly disallowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069). Don’t do that.

   - An exception to the above is [cross-posting between different language versions of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276251). This is allowed.