# What can we do with a cross-site duplicate that has answers on both sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I have answered [this question on *bioinformatics*](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/21358/14153).

It was first [asked on *Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76764237/6574038), and then, following [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764237/skip-splits-in-character-string#comment135332528_76764237), also asked on *[Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but without deleting it on *Stack Overflow*.

The question also got an answer on *Stack Overflow*. I am not sure if/how to flag it, or if I should copy my answer to *Stack Overflow*. So far I just noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764237/skip-splits-in-character-string#comment135354273_76764237), that I answered on *Bioinformatics*.

Does something need to be done, and if so, what and by whom?

Comment: Flagging is your best bet, explaining the reason in that (with links to the relevant other post(s)). Of course, with the strike, when any such flag would be handled is unknown.

Comment: @ThomA Done so, thanks! Please don't break the strike over this, mods!

Comment: Copying answers verbatim is something you should never do, really. Even if you have a valid reason like copying an answer from one site to another, it makes you look sketchy. I think mods can move answers, when they're willing to hit buttons that is :)

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a duplicate, haven't found the proper target yet though. e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272778/5211833 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270047/5211833 . Aside, I've personally flagged duplicated posts by the same user multiple times, with success. Questions might be on-topic on multiple sites, but don't need an answer on all of those.

Comment: @Gimby Unless the item got closed as being off-topic in the first site.  Then copying it verbatim to a second site where it is on topic could be completely reasonable.

Comment: Verbatim copies across sites is generally frowned upon, but if the same core question is on-topic on multiple sites, I don't think there's any reason it needs to be closed on one or the other. Sites are separate, and likely to generate answers from a perspective unique to the respective site. I don't think you need to do anything at all here if it's on-topic in both its locations.

Comment: @zcoop98 true, but the topic here is actually about copying an answer yes/no.

Answer (score 10):

#### Add links to navigate between questions in both ways

I don't know if a question can be marked as a duplicate of a question from another website.

In the meantime, we can use this advice from [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/237701) (emphasis mine):

> Occasionally, people are interested in different perspectives on the same fundamental question. There are many Stack Exchange sites with overlapping topic spaces, and it can be useful to get a "second opinion". Even then, however, it's best to tailor your question to each site. **Ideally, you should link to the question on the other site and explain what you hope to learn from asking another community.**

So adding a comment with a link to the other version, **on the 2 websites**, would help users to switch to the same question in the other context.

Comment: *I don't know if a question can be marked as a duplicate of a question from another website.* - it can't, unfortunately, which is a problem in general for later duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

## The general case

If you find a question that has been posted on multiple sites (the same exact question, word-for-word):

Flag the question for moderator attention.  Simultaneously cross-posting the same question on multiple sites is frowned upon.  Pick one site where you think it's best for the question to appear.  Flag the copy on the other site for moderator attention, and suggest that they close that copy.  You can optionally link to the official policy in the flag text if you wish.

Cross-posting is controversial.  Some people think that there is no problem with it.  Some think that it is problematic or should be prohibited.  The official policy is here: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917)

I am describing the practice I have taken.  I have found that on many sites, including Stack Overflow, the approach I've listed here is well-received.  My opinion is that there is no need to keep both copies open -- if they are cross-linked, then anyone who wants to answer can follow the links to go to the copy that is open and answer over there.  Also, my experience is that keeping multiple copies open is frequently detrimental -- it fragments discussion, improvements/clarifications to the question on one site often don't copied over to the other one, etc.  These are just my personal views and opinions, based on my experiences on the sites that I frequent.  Please understand that others have a different view, and I think their views are reasonable as well.

Finally, you emphasized that in this situation both copies have answers.  I think the approach listed above is still reasonable.  One approach is to close one copy, and cross-link.  Then anyone who encounters one copy will see the links and be able to see the other answers on the other copy.  Another approach is to close one copy and ask the moderators to migrate it to the other site; and then on that site, flag for moderators to ask the moderators to merge the two copies.  That will put both answers in one place, and have a single authoritative location to go to find all answers to that question.  That is more work and I'm not sure whether it is worth the hassle, but it is also a valid solution, in my opinion.

## This specific case

This is not a classic cross-post.  The question is not word-for-word identical on both sites.  As such, I am not sure whether "cross-site duplicate" is quite the right way to describe this situation.  It seems a bit unusual to me.  And I'm not sure what the right response to this specific situation is.

In this case, the copy on Bioinformatics appears to be a better-formulated question.  It is more detailed, and explains more clearly the problem statement.  It was edited significantly with additional information and clarifications that is not found in the question on Stack Overflow.  I find the question on Stack Overflow hard to understand and I don't think it is clearly specified enough to answer.  There is information that is important for understanding the problem in the comments, but that information was never included in the Stack Overflow question itself.

Therefore, in this case I believe the copy on SO should be closed as 'unclear what you're asking'.  This also happens to eliminate the problem of a cross-posted question, at least for now.

I don't believe you should post your answer to both sites.

Comment: In general, this might be reasonable advice.  However, this *particular* question complies with that policy by (fairly extensively) tailoring the question to the different audiences: the Stack Overflow question is described in generic terms any programmer can understand, while the Bioinformatics question approaches it from a more bioinformatics-centered approach.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse, excellent point.  Thank you for pointing out the flaw in my answer.  After reading both questions more closely, I've revised my answer.  I welcome any feedback you might have.

Comment: For effective cross-linking we should not use comments as they may vanish in the future. Maybe there should be an emphasis on cross-linking  inside the question body.