# Is it ok to ask a question on SO and then post it on a different site?

Tags: discussion

I have a [question about the `Eigen` library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757758/why-does-passing-temporaries-of-eigen-expressions-cause-access-to-undefined-memo), which is quite specific and relatively likely to go unanswered, although there's always a chance someone with knowledge on this topic might answer it.

The Eigen forums on the other hand are full of people who know a lot about this topic. Unfortunately, there are many more people with questions than there are people to answer them, so many questions there also go unanswered.

To maximise the chance that my question will be answered, is it frowned upon / disallowed to post my question on a third-party forum as well as on SO?

Comment: So long as it's not a duplicate on the stack site, there's no way one could say "Duplicate of derp.com/yourquestionhere" because it's not a stack network. Stack rules do not go past this domain :D

Comment: Does stack overflow own your question which you wrote, and can they prevent you from putting that content elsewhere? Absolutely not.

Comment: To add to what Aziz said it is __encouraged__ to perform as much research about your question as possible and post what you find in your question, if it answers your question - post it as an answer.

Comment: Please, please, please, please, please, please, please, please: if you find an answer on the forum, update your Stack Overflow question. If you find an answer on Stack Overflow, update your forum thread. There's nothing worse on the internet than finding that mysterious stranger with the **same exact problem you have**, but the thread is from 2008 and just dies with no resolution. What happened? Did you solve the problem? Did your house burn down? Don't just disappear, please!

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: Close question?

Comment: @SterlingArcher So, uh, things like "stackoverflow.com" and "unix.stackexchange.com"?  <wink wink nudge nudge>

Comment: @Izkata I said stack network as well..?

Comment: @SterlingArcher More referring to the last sentence, "Stack rules do not go past this domain"

Comment: Well it's too late to edit domain to network, soooo oops.

Comment: To those trying to close this question, please *read* my question and the cited duplicate. They're not the same. Nor is the answer to that question. They are different questions and different answers.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> is it frowned upon / disallowed to post my question on a third-party forum as well as on SO?

No, it is not. You are free to ask you question on any site you like as long as it helps you. However, cross-posting the exact same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites is not allowed.

If you get an answer elsewhere, it would be nice to self-answer your Stack Overflow question for the benefit of future visitors. Make sure to include the *actual information* in the body of the answer, rather than just a link to the original content, in case of eventual link rot.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62106/should-i-accept-my-own-answer-which-i-got-from-asking-the-same-question-on-a-dif

Comment: @Arman: Actually, it may depend on the policy of the other forum. For example, due do its license, the content of SO can be freely reproduced elsewhere *with proper attribution*; you should check with the forum whether you are allowed to reproduce the answer (in parts or in full) and under which rules. Of course, this does not apply if you complete reformulate it, since then there is no copyright issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you're the one that originally wrote the post then you can copy it however you wish, SO doesn't take your copyright away from you.

Comment: @Flimm: yes, however when you copy from another author, then you need to reference its nickname and (I think) give the link to its post.

Comment: Why can't I post a question both on SO and, say, CS.SE, when I cross-link them as described? Where's the difference between that and posting a question on the SE network and some other forum?

Comment: @Bergi The difference is that in the SE network Questions can be migrated to another site if they fit better there. In having stuff an "the best" place you have a single source of information which is easier to keep up to date etc.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Those migrations are more a theoretical tool than an actively used one - at least to me. There are many gray areas where a mod won't move a question, and it might be valuable in both communities.

Comment: @Bergi. I don't know about SE in general, but I do know that Christianity and Biblical Hermeneutics allow cross-posting *as long as the question is tailored for each community*. Word-for-word, or even substantially similar, cross-posting is disallowed.

Comment: Although I largely agree with this, however I think that you should also mention that you posted elsewhere (and preferably even link). That applies to both (all) locations that you post. Nothing is so annoying to post an elaborate answer only to find out the problem was already solved elsewhere (or to find out that more information was provided elsewhere).

Answer (score -11):

lol what kind of question is this? You can ask whoever you want, wherever you want. There is no "third party" like SO is some kind of main website that you are obligated to ask questions on.

You are basically asking random people on a website for permission to ask the same question elsewhere?

.........

Comment: ["Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251475/839601)

Comment: No; this user is asking a targeted group of people on a website if specific behavior related to use of that website would result in loss of privileges or status on the website. That's what kind of question this is. Welcome to Meta.

Comment: Yes but why would members of SO care if you post on other websites and how would they find out? EDIT: Oh wait nvm I understand now. sorry