# Cannot mark question duplicate on another part of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I discovered [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229537/arduino-deep-sleep-listen-to-serial) that was identical to one asked on [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/atmega328-very-deep-sleep-and-listen-to-serial). I had already answered it on that other site.

I tried to flag it as a duplicate but the link was rejected because the `The duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow`.

Is there any mechanism for handling this sort of thing? Otherwise people will post duplicate questions on multiple sites, and there is no (easy?) way of flagging them, so potentially different people try to answer them in multiple places.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31414422/2564301) is one that came in today, and its identical [RE.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/9348/2959) twin.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes: close, with a reason of "other". (As a relatively new user, you don't have that option yet, so you'll have to use a flag.)

The unsportsman-like behavior of this poster - asking the same within the space of 2 minutes in different SE sites - has been earning him downvotes. See also [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251469/2564301) <strike>(from memory, there is also a better precedent)</strike>.

See also Meta's [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068), answered with a hearthy "**NO**" (*sic* the capitals and boldness).

Comment: I could have closed the question on the other site, where I have more rep, however I only just spotted it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Another one (sigh). http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13380/how-to-program-for-two-arduinos-with-different-code-but-share-one-same-h vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357207/how-to-program-for-two-arduinos-with-different-code-but-share-one-same-h/

Comment: @NickGammon: the two excellent answers (according to my limited experience) show Arduino.SE is quite a good place. Also, since the question on SO has no answers, it's logical to close this one, referring to the other site for the answers in case someone needs to know. Your second example has been officially migrated.

Comment: However that [Meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) had the paragraph: *Note: I do not consider any sites valid migration targets until they are out of public beta. There are no guarantees that a current SE site will live past beta.*

Comment: @Nick: that concers a moderator processing a request for migration. This, and my duplicate above, are *plain duplicates* posted by the same author.