# How to handle question titles that end up being irrelevant corner-cases to the problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, title, google

This issue plagues Stack Overflow questions. Do you encounter this a lot?

*Click on a high ranking Google result of your carefully crafted keyword-rich query*

## "How does foo work with bar"

*Perfect! This sounds relevant to what i'm looking for. (click)*

> Question: I'm trying to use foo and bar but i'm getting this error about baz. Halp?

*Ohh kkk, so this is a corner-case issue, not actually what is promised from the title.*

> Top Answer: Your baz is leaking. Just run the blip command and that should fix the error.

*Congratulations for solving the corner case, the answer is now **completely** unrelated to the title.*

*Frownie face.*

**Edits**:

The deeper question here is "Could there be a way to make it less of an issue to start with?" - as eloquently spelled out and addressed [below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299812/921629) by @[gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat)

Pretty much duplicate of [How to save the world](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time) which explains & demonstrates the issue much better, particularly how it relates to Google search results. Kudos [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299786/how-to-handle-question-titles-that-end-up-being-irrelevant-corner-cases-to-the-p#comment223436_299786)'s comment. See also the [related feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209905/withdraw-questions-with-no-useful-answers-from-google-index).

Comment: You would edit the title to make it more representative of the question. What more do you think should be done?

Comment: This is a gripping some people have since ancient times. The only solution is editing the title.

Comment: Now whether to edit the title of this meta-post.  I was swindled into clicking this question by its outrageous title only to find I actually understood the question.

Comment: Sometimes it can even still be incorrect to change the title to "How do deal with baz error", rather the answer would best fit with a title such as "What command needed to fix leaking". The problem is about this 3-step disconnect between title > question > answer. The whole sequence needs rewriting...

Comment: Robert Harvey posted on this as well several years ago: [How to save the world, one question title at a time?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201940)

Comment: @JoshCaswell that question you linked hit the nail on the head, explained & demonstrated the issue much better than me. Perhaps post an answer here and suggest this question as duplicate of that one?

Comment: one [Cannot mark question duplicate on another part of Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299120/839601), otherwise I'd vote as duplicate instead of answering ("How to save the world..." is posted at other meta)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, once you landed on such a question, the apparent thing to do was to edit the title to better fit the question text. That way, you would help future readers.

Of course this leaves a question: **[Could there be a way to make it less of an issue to start with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201940/165773)**

Math.SE folks recently [bragged at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260981/165773) that they found a way to make it less troublesome:

> To some extent, uninformative titles can be detected automatically but this requires a site-specific approach. On Mathematics, some community members were sufficiently tired of uninformative titles to
>
> 1. Collect the [signs of weak titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/retitling-questions-a-modest-proposal/8781#8781)
> 2. Write a [meta post on writing good titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)
> 3. Propose a [feature request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16573/) for automatic check
> 4. ... and it [was implemented](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17012/).
>
> Not to say that the problem disappeared — terrible questions still have terrible titles — but the users writing decent questions got some just-in-time help.

Math folks didn't tell (maybe because they don't have it there) but at Stack Overflow, even the refusal of the user to follow a suggestion to improve the title may be useful: it can serve as [yet another signal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298847/839601) to trigger pushing the question into Triage review, where it wouldn't bother readers.